# how to find reason for 100% CPU utilization on AWS EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I've fleet of EC2 instances : A and B (both are in same AWS account, same Linux OS version, same region, but different AZ and under different load balances ). 
when i give same load to fleet of EC2 instances A and B ; both behave differently. 
EC2 A works normally with average CPU utilization upto 60% ; on other hand EC2 B shows spike in CPU utilization upto 100% then it start again from 0 and same effort found in other instances in fleet.

Anyone experienced this in past?

Comment: Have you already checked the cloudwatch logs?

Comment: Log into the node and see see what it's doing under load?

Comment: how and which logs to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analysis it was found that couple of security patches getting executed; which was causing these spikes.

Comment: how you checked it?

Answer (score 1):

ssh to the host B, see the system activity via top, look for the process consuming most of the CPU. 
also you can inspect the process with "lsof" command or 
ps -fp *"PID of the process"*

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me twice now with a MS Server instance running EC2. In both cases it was the MS Update Service which had taken 100% of CPU and burnt off all my CPU credits.

The only way to get back on and fix it was to set "Instance T2/T3 Unlimited" and stop/disable the MS Update Service.